# Deserialize inconsistent JSON property

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization, json-deserialization

Hopefully someone can help me with the following inconsistency occurring in a large JSON file that I am attempting to deserialize using Newtonsoft.Json.

One of the properties of the object occasionally appears as:

```
"roles": [
  {
    "field1" : "value",
    "field2" : "value"
  }
]
```

While other times that same property appears as:

```
"roles": {
  "roles": [
    {
      "field1" : "value",
      "field2" : "value"
    }
  ]
}
```

For reference, this property is implemented in its class as:

```
[JsonProperty("roles")]
public List<Role> Roles { get; set; }
```

**What I need to happen is that whenever the second situation above occurs, the object contents are deserialized like the first situation. i.e. the "outer" object is discarded/ignored**

I have managed to handle another inconsistency in this file when a separate property sometimes occurs as an object and sometimes as an array using the following approach in its class definition:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(SingleValueArrayConverter<Address>))]
public List<Address> Location { get; set; }
```

And implemented as:

```
public class SingleValueArrayConverter<T> : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        object retVal = new Object();
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
        {
            T instance = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader, typeof(T));
            retVal = new List<T>() { instance };
        }
        else if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartArray)
        {
            retVal = serializer.Deserialize(reader, objectType);
        }
        return retVal;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

However, I am unable to work out this issue.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Can't you fix the actual bug? What you are trying to do is to sweep the actual bug under the carpet and pretend it isn't there. This will cause even more pain down the road.

Comment: Hi @RosdiKasim , Unfortunately the JSON file I am deserializing is provided from a 3rd party which I have no control over. In total there are around 1.5 million objects spread across 7 files which I am deserializing. I have been successful processing 6 of those files however in this one, this issue occurs. Cheers

Comment: the 2nd case isn't valid JSON unless there is a typo. Needs a ] to match the [

Comment: apologies @GarrGodfrey This was a typo, I have corrected it

Comment: yuck. You could try to identify the case, like in the other example, but you'd need to deserialize to a `dynamic`, get the first property value, serialize it, then deserialize it as the correct type.

Comment: You can parse it to `JObject` and find the inner `roles` array for all cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle this inconsistency with a `JsonConverter` also.  It will be a little different than the one you have, but the idea is very similar:

```
public class ArrayOrWrappedArrayConverter<T> : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(List<T>).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken token = JToken.Load(reader);
        if (token.Type == JTokenType.Array)
        {
            return CreateListFromJArray((JArray)token, serializer);
        }
        if (token.Type == JTokenType.Object)
        {
            JObject wrapper = (JObject)token;
            JProperty prop = wrapper.Properties().FirstOrDefault();
            if (prop.Value.Type == JTokenType.Array)
            {
                return CreateListFromJArray((JArray)prop.Value, serializer);
            }
        }
        // If the JSON is not what we expect, just return an empty list.
        // (Could return null or throw an exception here instead if desired.)
        return new List<T>();
    }

    private List<T> CreateListFromJArray(JArray array, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        List<T> list = new List<T>();
        serializer.Populate(array.CreateReader(), list);
        return list;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite => false;

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then just add the converter to your `Roles` property and you should be good to go:

```
[JsonProperty("roles")]
[JsonConverter(typeof(ArrayOrWrappedArrayConverter<Role>))]
public List<Role> Roles { get; set; }
```

Working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/F6qgQB

Comment: Thanks so much for this! It worked perfectly. If you are feeling adventurous I have identified the final issue in this file which I believe can be handled the same way however I'm struggling to work it out. I have asked the question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63064260/deserialize-inconsistent-json-property-nested-object-in-an-array

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way (not necessarily the cleanest) would be to manually alter the string before deserialising -

```
jsonString = jsonString.replace("\"roles\": {", "\"rolesContainer\": {");
jsonString = jsonString.replace("\"roles\":{", "\"rolesContainer\": {");
```

and then in your main code you would have both rolesContainer and roles as fields - and then merge them after

```
public List<Role> roles { get; set; }
public RoleContainer rolesContainer { get; set; }
public class RoleContainer {
    Public List<Role> roles;
}
```

it's dirty, but it should work