# Deserialize inconsistent JSON property (nested object in an array)

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization, json-deserialization

I am attempting to deserialize a JSON file that has been provided from a third party which contains inconsistent properties. I am using Newtonsoft.Json. Unfortunately I have no control over the creation of these files so I am stuck with handling what is provided.

I have already had a solution provided to another issue in this file which is documented / answered here [Deserialize inconsistent JSON property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63045851/deserialize-inconsistent-json-property) and this is the final issue that I have identified in this file. I believe this issue can be handled in the same manner however I am struggling to work it out.

This issue is as follows.

The file contains the followng property:

```
"rolePerson": [
    {
      "firstName": "John",
      "lastName": "Doe",
      "middleNames": "Smith",
      "title": "mr"
    }
  ]
```

However ocasionally the file contains:

```
  "rolePerson": [
    {
      "rolePerson": {
         "firstName": "John",
         "lastName": "Doe",
         "middleNames": "Smith",
         "title": "mr"
      }
    }
  ]
```

**What I need to happen is that whenever the second situation above occurs, the object contents are deserialized like the first situation. i.e. the "inner" object wrapper is discarded/ignored and the "inner" object contents are handled only.**

This is a tricky situation but I believe incorporating the approach provided in the linked solution above is able to be utilized somehow.

Comment: In this situation, what is a reliable way to detect whether the array item object is a wrapper that needs to be discarded?  Is it that the item has only a single property and its value is another object?  Is it that the item has a property with the same name as the outer array?  Or some other criteria?

Comment: Hi @BrianRogers, the most reliable way is that the item has a property with the same name as the outer array. The second situation shown above is the only inconsistent way provided in the file. Otherwise it is as the first situation shows or as an empty array. Thanks for your time on this!

Comment: Assuming we model the regular `"rolePerson"` with a `RolePerson` POCO, will the nested property always be some fixed name, here `"rolePerson"`?  Or could the same POCO have a different wrapped name depending on where it is used?

Comment: Because if the name `"rolePerson"` is fixed you could just use a private set-only property to bind its value, see this demo fiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/DCrxV7.  No converter required in this case.

Comment: thanks @dbc for your comment and sample fiddle. This solved my issue. I have posted your answer to this question and mentioned you for recognition.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comment response from **dbc** I was able to solve this issue using their advice.

For reference, the modification to my RolePerson class to handle this issue is as follows

```
public class RolePerson    
{
    [JsonProperty("rolePerson")]
    RolePerson NestedSerialization 
    {
        set
        {
            this.firstName = value?.firstName;
            this.lastName = value?.lastName;
            this.middleNames = value?.middleNames;
            this.title = value?.title;
        }
    }
    
    public string firstName { get; set; } 
    public string lastName { get; set; } 
    public string middleNames { get; set; } 
    public string title { get; set; } 
}
```

A link to their demo fiddle can be seen [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DCrxV7)